# Is there a solution for the three body problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, three-body-problem

Is there a valid solution to the [three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)? why has it puzzled mathematicians and physicists for so long?

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia on this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Comment: I don't think it does puzzle mathematicians/physicist, I think we quite comfortably know that there's no general analytic solution for the equations of motion.